# Is it possible to have two Win 10 user accounts running simultaneously, with one used locally and one used via RDP?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts

I need to allow someone to remotely connect to my windows 10 computer, and am wondering if this is possible:

I have two user accounts right now on my computer, one for me to work on and one for my friend remotely. I want to use my user account locally for myself, and I want to allow him to RDP and log into the other account when he needs to work without disturbing my computer experience.

In other words, I don't want to have to stop what I am doing and log off of my user account when he needs to access his account remotely. Can two user accounts run simultaneously in this regard, with one being connected to via RDP?

If so, can you please explain how to set it up properly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Two unsupported methods are to use the [RDP Wrapper Library](https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/releases) or [modify termsrv.dll](http://woshub.com/how-to-allow-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-10/). There is no supported / Microsoft sanctioned method.

Answer (score 10):

Natively no. The reason is the Windows user license for a work station is single user.

That said, users have patched termsrv.dll for every version of Windows.   For windows 10 you might want to check [here](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/545-multiple-rdp-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-10)

Should the link expire, or the reader of this answer is looking for a different Windows version then google "concurrent sessions termsrv.dll Windows 10" for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [project](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) on github called rdpwrap that does it automatically for most windows version